# Trying to sign XML with XmlSec in command line, keep getting "missing file errors"?

Tags: xml, file, command-line, digital-signature, xmlsec

No matter which order of commands I use, I keep getting similar error messages:

With

```
xmlsec --sign --output signedfile.xml --pkcs FISKAL.p12 --pwd Password --trusted-pem root_ca.pem --id-attr:Id file.xml
```

I get

```
Error: ⟨file⟩ parameter is required for this command
```

If I try

```
xmlsec --sign --id-attr:Id --pkcs FISKAL.p12 --pwd Password --trusted-pem root_ca.pem --output signedfile.xml file.xml
```

I get

```
Error: filename is expected instead of parameter "--pwd".
Error: invalid parameters
```

And in the case of

```
xmlsec --sign --output signedfile.xml --id-attr:Id --trusted-pem root_ca.pem --pkcs FISKAL.p12 --pwd Password file.xml
```

it's similar:

```
Error: filename is expected instead of parameter "--pkcs12".
Error: invalid parameters
```

Below each error message is the line: `Usage: xmlsec ⟨command⟩ [⟨options⟩] [⟨files⟩]`

Why does xmlsec keep thinking I'm missing a file? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `--id-attr:Id` parameter is incomplete. Either remove it or you need to specify it like this:

```
   --id-attr[:<attr-name>] [<node-namespace-uri>:]<node-name>

          adds attributes <attr-name> (default value "id") from all  nodes
          with<node-name>  and  namespace <node-namespace-uri> to the list
          of known ID attributes; this is a hack and if you can use DTD or
          schema  to  declare  ID  attributes  instead  (see  "--dtd-file"
          option), I don't know what else might be broken in your applica‐
          tion when you use this hack
```

There's `node-name` you need to specify because it's not optional. You do specify `attr-name` but it is optional. This might not be what you wanted.